# insert value and rows depended on two cell values - sheet to sheet VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a excel sheet with a lot of information to support a project. this is working as a list of all options for this product.

the struggle is to make some ranges of data into specific cells in SiDAQ sheeted from SiDAQ_Template Sheetet. the ranges can go from 1 row to 51 rows, and these should also be dynamic inserted and removed again (like a curtain you roll up and down depended on the choices in the SiDAQ Sheet)

i have tried to write some down, but none make sense for me.

```
Sub test()
defining the worksheets used for the copy/paste of templates.
Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SiDAQ")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SiDAQ_Template")
defining the ranges of the templates, easier naming in the code
With ws2
    Dim rng1 As Range: Set rng1 = Range("E2:F2") 'Speed
    Dim rng2 As Range: Set rng2 = Range("E4:F4") 'Count
    Dim rng3 As Range: Set rng3 = Range("E8:F8") 'EL2202 (1 ms)
    Dim rng4 As Range: Set rng4 = Range("E9:F9") 'EL2202 (1 sec)
    Dim rng5 As Range: Set rng5 = Range("E10:F10") 'EL2202 (1 hour)
    Dim rng6 As Range: Set rng6 = Range("E11:F11") 'PPS
    Dim rng7 As Range: Set rng7 = Range("E13:F13") 'I 4…20mA
    Dim rng8 As Range: Set rng8 = Range("E16:F16") 'I 0...20mA
    Dim rng9 As Range: Set rng9 = Range("E18:F18") 'V ±30V
    Dim rng10 As Range: Set rng10 = Range("E19:F19") 'V ±10V
    Dim rng11 As Range: Set rng11 = Range("E21:F21") 'V ±5V
    Dim rng12 As Range: Set rng12 = Range("E23:F23") 'V ±2.5V
    Dim rng13 As Range: Set rng13 = Range("E24:F24") 'V ±1.25V
    Dim rng14 As Range: Set rng14 = Range("E25:F25") 'V ±640mV
    Dim rng15 As Range: Set rng15 = Range("E26:F26") 'V ±320mV
    Dim rng16 As Range: Set rng16 = Range("E27:F27") 'V ±160mV
    Dim rng17 As Range: Set rng17 = Range("E28:F28") 'V ±80mV
    Dim rng18 As Range: Set rng18 = Range("E29:F29") 'V ±40mV
    Dim rng19 As Range: Set rng19 = Range("E30:F30") 'I ±20mA
    Dim rng20 As Range: Set rng20 = Range("E31:F31") 'R 2W Ohm
    Dim rng21 As Range: Set rng21 = Range("E32:F32") 'R 3W Ohm
    Dim rng22 As Range: Set rng22 = Range("E33:F33") 'R 4W Ohm
    Dim rng23 As Range: Set rng23 = Range("E34:F34") 'RTD 3W °C
    Dim rng24 As Range: Set rng24 = Range("E36:F36") 'RTD 4W °C
    Dim rng25 As Range: Set rng25 = Range("E37:F37") 'SG 1/4 3W 350Ohm mV/V
    Dim rng26 As Range: Set rng26 = Range("E38:F38") 'SG 1/4 3W 120Ohm mV/V
    Dim rng27 As Range: Set rng27 = Range("E39:F39") 'SG 1/2 3W mV/V
    Dim rng28 As Range: Set rng28 = Range("E40:F40") 'SG 1/2 5W mV/V
    Dim rng29 As Range: Set rng29 = Range("E41:F41") 'SG 1/1 4W mV/V
    Dim rng30 As Range: Set rng30 = Range("E42:F42") 'SG 1/1 6W mV/V
    Dim rng31 As Range: Set rng31 = Range("E43:F43") 'IEPE
    Dim rng32 As Range: Set rng32 = Range("E44:F44") 'Thermocouples
    Dim rng33 As Range: Set rng33 = Range("E46:F54") 'Power
    Dim rng34 As Range: Set rng34 = Range("E55:F78") 'Corrosion
    Dim rng35 As Range: Set rng35 = Range("E103:F104") 'ComNav
    Dim rng36 As Range: Set rng36 = Range("E107:F129") 'RisoDau
    Dim rng37 As Range: Set rng37 = Range("E153:F160") 'GPS
    Dim rng38 As Range: Set rng38 = Range("E169:F178") 'RotorAzimut
    Dim rng39 As Range: Set rng39 = Range("E189:F239") 'Camilla Bauer
    Dim rng40 As Range: Set rng40 = Range("E291:F298") 'PTP
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'for quicker operation
    For Each Cells In Column(5)
        If Cells(Column, 5) = "EL*" Then

    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The different ranges are depended on if there is an "EL something" in column 5(E) 
in SiDAQ sheet and if word matching rngXX in column 15(O) also in SiDAQ Sheet

then insert the ranges in the same row as the EL in column 5 and column 15 in column 37 (AK) and down while inserting blank rows matching the rows of the range pasted into column AK(37)

Comment: `Set rng1 = Range("E2:F2")` should be `Set rng1 = .Range("E2:F2")` - note the full stop before `Range` - this enables your `With` to be applied.

Comment: Also, don't use `=` to test with wildcards - use `Like`.